# Number of lines in a label and macOS

Tags: swift, macos, storyboard

In `iOS` we can control the number of lines in `Storyboard > Attributes > Number of lines`. We can put 0 to make an undetermined number and then the label adapts to the content.

Also programatically: `label1.numberOfLines = 0`

I do not see an equivalent in `macOS`. I can option enter manually in `Storyboard`, if I want to create a new line. But, that does not solve the problem if the text changes dynamically.

How can make multiple lines and let a label adapt to the content in `macOS`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the following properties in the Xcode interface builder:

- Choose 'Wraps' from Layout
- Choose 'Character Wrap' (or Word Wrap) from Line Break
- Option 'Uses Single Line Mode' must be unchecked

Programatically (the key is to use the underlying cell of the NSTextField):

```
let textfield: NSTextField = NSTextField(wrappingLabelWithString: "This is a very long text that requires a line break.")
textfield.frame = NSRect(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, width: 128.0, height: 96.0)
(textfield.cell as? NSTextFieldCell)?.isEditable = false
(textfield.cell as? NSTextFieldCell)?.wraps = true
(textfield.cell as? NSTextFieldCell)?.usesSingleLineMode = false
(textfield.cell as? NSTextFieldCell)?.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.byWordWrapping

self.view.addSubview(textfield)
```

Comment: Do you know how to control that programmatically?

Comment: Hello, sorry, I was at work, I have edited my answer.

Comment: It does not work for me. Perhaps I am doing something wrong? I have put your code first in the viewDidLoad. Then I tried to put it in a button. The text does not appear

Comment: I have modified the code slightly (I have added a frame). The text will be wrapped. When setting `wraps` to false and `usesSingleLineMode` to true, the text will be cut, so it seems to be working.